# Como sacar una tupla de un JSON de acuerdo a una posición especifica en python?

Tags: python, json, tuplas

Eso pues, tengo este mensaje en JSON:

```
mensaje = {"13":"17.800","14":"75.000","15":"13.300","16":"17.800","17":"21.200","18":"58.000","19":"12.600","20":"765.600","21":"1038.400","22":"0.900","23":"1.300","24":"152.000","25":"152.000","26":"0.000","27":"72.000","28":"0.700","29":"127.000","30":"3.404","31":"17.800"}
```

Quiero obtener una tupla del mensaje, por ejemplo la primera, que saldría esto: `"13:"17.800"`
En pocas palabras, sería `mensaje[0]`si `mensaje` fuese una lista

Comment: `mensaje.items()[0]`

Comment: No funciona, pongo ````print(mensaje.items()[0])```` y me sale ````TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not subscriptable```` en la consola

Comment: Se me olvidaba que en las versiones actuales devuelve un `dict_items`, debe de ser `list(mensaje.items())[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, para acceder a ese datos escribe `list(mensaje.items())[0]`, te devuelve una tuple:

```
type(list(mensaje.items())[0])
-> tuple

print(list(mensaje.items())[0])
-> ('13', '17.800')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay un problema inicial, lo que tienes serializado en un JSON es básicamente un diccionario y estos, dependiendo de la versión de Python, no siempre hay garantía de orden en os elementos, por que de hecho, el orden en sí no es algo fundamental para un diccionario. Si mal no recuerdo, desde la versión 3.6 ya podemos confiar en el orden de un diccionario, por lo que fácilmente podrías hacer algo así:

```
import json

d = json.loads(mensaje)
k, v = list(d.items())[0]
print('El primer elemento {0} tiene un valor de {1}'.format(k, v))

El primer elemento 13 tiene un valor de 17.800
```

En caso que estuviera con una versión anterior, podrías apoyarte en un `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = json.loads(mensaje, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```